# Merge two list of type Long and add to existing map in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two list both of type Long, say `ListA` and `ListB`.

I want to merge these into a `Map<Long, Long>` such that `ListA` becomes key and and `ListB` becomes value.
Here catch is I want to add these key value pair to an existing map.

I know how to parse the lists and return a new map object (using `Collectors.toMap`). My problem is to add to an existing map, may be something like:

```
Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<Long, Long>;
// ... entries added to map
ListA.stream().forEach(a -> {
    map.put(a, <get 0th element of ListB somehow>);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option:

```
Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
IntStream.range(0, ListA.size())
    .forEach(i -> {
        map.put(ListA.get(i), ListB.get(i));
    });
```

### Demo

But honestly, I see nothing wrong here with using a regular pre Java 8 enhanced `for` loop:

```
// assuming both lists have the same size
for (int i=0; i < ListA.size(); ++i) {
    map.put(ListA.get(i), ListB.get(i);
}
```

It's concise, easy to read and maintain, and won't turn the head of anyone reviewing your code.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that those lists have the same size:

```
 Map<Long, Long> map = IntStream.range(0, listA.size())
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(listA::get, listB::get));


yourOtherMap.putAll(map);
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll make this my last comment here, I started that *festival* because you said *I'm new to java-8* and wanted to provided  the proper directions (being a good person you know). and the keyword for that *scrape* is **if**